# Stop sqoop from converting datetime to bigint

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Recently I noticed that whenever I ingest from a SQL database using Sqoop, all datetime fields are converted to a bigint (epoch * 1000) instead of to String.

Important to note: I'm storing as parquet.

I have been trying a bunch of sqoop flags like `"--map-column-java"` but I don't want to manually define this for hundreds of columns in thousands of tables.

What flag am I missing to prevent this sqoop behaviour?

It seems that sqoop didn't do this when storing in plain text.

Comment: Yes with plain text import sqoop is converting datetime to string

Comment: How do I get sqoop to behave like this for parquet files as well then?

Comment: Hanvar I have not used sqoop to store data in parquet files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of letting sqoop do its arcane magic on my tables, I decided to do the following:

1. Ingest to a temporary table, stored as text.
2. Create a table (if not exists) like the temporary table, stored as parquet
3. insert overwrite the text stored temporary table into the parquet stored table

This allows for proper date formatting without the hassle with (maybe not existing) configuration and settings tweaking in Sqoop.

The only tradoff is that it's slightly slower

Comment: But then if you do an incremental update on that same parquet table with sqoop, you get a mix of text files and parquet files (if you let sqoop still use text)... and as per today (july 2020) sqoop does not raise an exception when you do that.